# REST: How to send YAML payload (Java)

Tags: java, rest, jackson, jersey, yaml

How does one send a yml payload to a POST entpoint using Java.

---

### Environment

Request:

- language: Java
- lib used: Jersey

Target (**already exists**):

- REST endpoint
- type POST
- payload content YAML

---

### Code

I used to use this to achieve the same:

```
curl --noproxy '*' -X POST --header 'content-type: application/x-yml' --data-binary @file.yaml --url "http://my.yaml.endpoint.com"
```

I tried something like this:

```
private Client client;
private ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());

YMLPayload yml= null;
    try {
        yml = mapper.readValue(yml, YMLPayload.class);
    } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

Response res = client
                .target("http://my.yaml.endpoint.com")
                .request(/* which mediatype? */)
                .header("content-type", "application/x-yml")
                .post(/* how to transform the data? */);
```

---

As I'm fairly new to this Topic I might have overlooked something.

Comment: What problem do you face? Do you get an error? Or are you asking opinions about the tools / methods that could be used (which would be off topic)?

Comment: I dont know how to tell the `request`, that the data (YMLPayload) should be submitted as yml and not as JSON. MediaType does not offer YAML.
And `post` expects an Entity wich in turn offers a method `json(Object)`.

Comment: Ok, but what was the result of your attempt? Fior example did you just try to put the yml as byte[]?

Comment: Thanks for your reply but no I didnt try it out as I also had some backend issues. How do I pass it as a the byte[]? Does post accept a byte[] as its param ?
Unfortunately I cant check it right now cause Im not at work. But I will try it tomorrow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Using `JacksonYAMLProvider` in your JAX-RS `Client`

Jackson has a module for handling YAML serialization/deserialization in JAX-RS. It provides the [`MessageBodyReader`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/ext/MessageBodyReader.html) and  [`MessageBodyWriter`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/ext/MessageBodyWriter.html) needed for binding YAML content to and from Java objects. To use it, add the following dependency to your project:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-yaml-provider</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.7</version>
</dependency>
```

Then register the [`JacksonYAMLProvider`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-jaxrs-providers/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/jaxrs/yaml/JacksonYAMLProvider.html) class and perform your request as follows:

```java
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient().register(new JacksonYAMLProvider());

Response response = client.target("http://example.org")
        .request().accept(YAMLMediaTypes.APPLICATION_JACKSON_YAML)
        .post(Entity.entity(foo, YAMLMediaTypes.APPLICATION_JACKSON_YAML_TYPE));
```

Where `foo` is the object that will be serialized as YAML.

If you need to fine-tune the YAML serialization/deserialization, you can pass an instance of [`YAMLMapper`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-dataformats-text/javadoc/yaml/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/yaml/YAMLMapper.html) to the [`JacksonYAMLProvider`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-jaxrs-providers/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/jaxrs/yaml/JacksonYAMLProvider.html) constructor:

```java
YAMLMapper mapper = new YAMLMapper();
mapper.disable(YAMLGenerator.Feature.WRITE_DOC_START_MARKER);

Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient().register(new JacksonYAMLProvider(mapper));
```

Once [there's no media type for YAML registered in IANA](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml), there's no official standard. The YAML media type used by Jackson is `application/yaml`. If you need to use `application/x-yml`, for example, you could override the [`hasMatchingMediaType()`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-jaxrs-providers/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/jaxrs/base/ProviderBase.html#hasMatchingMediaType(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType)) method from [`JacksonYAMLProvider`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-jaxrs-providers/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/jaxrs/yaml/JacksonYAMLProvider.html) according to your needs:

```java
JacksonYAMLProvider jacksonYAMLProvider = new JacksonYAMLProvider() {

    @Override
    protected boolean hasMatchingMediaType(MediaType mediaType) {
        return super.hasMatchingMediaType(mediaType) ||
                "x-yml".equalsIgnoreCase(mediaType.getSubtype());
    }
};

Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient().register(jacksonYAMLProvider);
```

### Using `YAMLMapper` directly

Alternatively, you could use the approach shown below, which doesn't depend on the Jackson YAML provider for JAX-RS.

```java
YAMLMapper mapper = new YAMLMapper();
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();

Response response = client.target("http://example.org")
        .request().accept("application/x-yml")
        .post(Entity.entity(mapper.writeValueAsString(foo), "application/x-yml"));
```

In this approach, `foo` is serialized as YAML using [`YAMLMapper`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-dataformats-text/javadoc/yaml/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/yaml/YAMLMapper.html) directly.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Your answer shows a very detailed solution and the one pirho showed.

Comment: I think it's obsolote. How will be this code in 2024 with jakarta? Could you update it?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your backend you could try to pass the data as plain string, like:

```
Entity<String> ymlEntity = Entity.entity(yml, "application/x-yml");     
client.target("http://my.yaml.endpoint.com")
    .request()
    .post(e);
```

Anyway the way to post the data is to create an `Entity<DT>` of it.